Looking for old Hindi telefilm I watched on Doordarshan in 1980's
I watched this Hindi telefilm on Doordarshan in 1980's.
It was a young Bengali couple, they had love marriage; wife is very educated and talented, but is housewife. She is probably more educated, and her husband although loves her is jealous.
Husband and wife get into contest who is more gifted in literature. They decide to submit essay in literature contest(very renowned).
Wife, as she is busy cooking, write her notes/manuscript.
Husband is very confident that he will score much better than his wife.
On the day when the results are announced in newspaper, the husband finds out that his name is not in the list, but is shocked to find that his wife won the top award. First he is sad that he lost, but suddenly realizes that his wife is really rare talent and gifted as this top award is very prestigious.
When he reaches home, he finds that wife has burned the manuscript as she felt sad that she put her husband down.
Finally, they reconcile.

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title
